# python - can lambda have more than one return

Tags: python, lambda, tuples

I know lambda doesn't have a return expression. Normally

```
def one_return(a):
    #logic is here
    c = a + 1
    return c
```

can be written:

```
lambda a : a + 1
```

How about write this one in a lambda function:

```
def two_returns(a, b):
    # logic is here
    c = a + 1
    d = b * 1
    return c, d
```

Comment: That's not more than one return, it's not even a single return with multiple values. It's one return with one value (which happens to be a tuple).

Comment: +1 @delnan's comment, this is a major reason I dislike Python's promotion of `,` to tuple all over the place.  It obfuscates what's actually going on.

Comment: @Izkata What? `,` is not "promoted to tuple", that's literally the syntax for tuple creation. And it's perfectly clear IMHO.

Comment: @delnan I mean, excluding the parens.  It's not obvious all the time, when they're excluded.

Comment: @Izkata Can you give an example where it is not obvious?

Comment: @lzkata: who gave you the idea that tuples should have parens? The parens are only for operator precedence purposes

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Because an expression such as this at the end of a function:

```
return a, b
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
return (a, b)
```

And there, you're really returning a single value: a tuple which happens to have two elements. So it's ok to have a lambda return a tuple, because it's a single value:

```
lambda a, b: (a, b) # here the return is implicit
```

Comment: in other words, it's a precedence issue. `,` has lower precedence than `lambda`

Answer (score 18):

Sure:

```
lambda a, b: (a + 1, b * 1)
```

Answer (score 11):

what about:

```
lambda a,b: (a+1,b*1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Print the table of 2 and 3 with a single range iteration.

```
>>> list(map(lambda n: n*2, range(1,11)))
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]


>>> list(map(lambda n: (n*2, n*3) , range(1,11)))
[(2, 3), (4, 6), (6, 9), (8, 12), (10, 15), (12, 18), (14, 21), (16, 24), (18, 27), (20, 30)]
```