# how to access variable and lambda defined inside a function(which is not defined in any class)?

Tags: python, lambda

I have very basic question. For some reason I'm not able to recall how to do it. How to access the variables defined in the function which is not declared in class. How to access `y` variable ? And how to pass the value for lambda ? And how to get back the value of `c` defined inside lambda ?

```
    def fun ():
        y = 100
        x = lambda c,s,y : c*s*y
```

Also how to pass the values to lambda from function ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python - can lambda have more than one return](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674004/python-can-lambda-have-more-than-one-return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `y` in lambda then don't specify it as an argument for the lambda:

```
def fun():
    y = 5
    x = lambda c, s: c*s*y
    return x(2, 3)

>>> fun()
30
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to pass the values to lambda from function ?

Comment: @sammy I'm not sure what you are asking. I've just passed `y` to the lambda. What exactly is what you don't understand?

Comment: If my `fun` function had only lambda then how to pass the values of `c`,`s` from `fun` function ?

Comment: @sammy Do you mean `def fun(a, b):` and then `return x(a, b)` in the code?

Comment: Yes. Similar to that. `a` and `b` values should be passed to lambda too.