# How to use Numpy Eig with Python Lambda function?

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

Can I use lambda function with numpy's eig function?

Test problem:

```
import numpy as np
class c1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mat1 = lambda num1:np.array([[num1,2],[3,4]])
        self.mat2 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
        self.eigVal, self.eigVec = lambda num1:np.linalg.eig(self.mat2+self.mat1(num1))
    def func1(self):
        print(self.mat1(10))
        print(self.eigVal(10))
c1().func1()
```

Error is `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object`.

Comment: `lambda` is a single function, and when you call it a single array that contains two arrays is produced. You cannot unpack that directly in the class, but you can do something like `self.eigFunc = lambda num1: np.linalg.eig(self.mat2 + self.mat1(num1))` and unpack the results later `eigval, eigvec = self.eigFunc(10)`

Comment: Interstingly, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16674091/10640063) says that you can return two values using lambda. But in my example I cant. When I adopt your suggestion its work. Thank you.

Comment: The `lambda` when called can return 2 values, but the lambda itself is one object.

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj. Now I understand non-iterable structure of `lambda`after I get error from the code below. 
`self.eigFunc = lambda num1: np.linalg.eig(self.mat1(num1)); self.eigenVal = lambda num1 : self.eigFunc(num1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@pietro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2237151/pietro). The solution is given in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66796565/how-to-use-numpy-eig-with-pyhton-lambda-function/66797611?noredirect=1#comment118075617_66796565).

Here is my working solution.

```py
import numpy as np
class c1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mat1 = lambda num1:np.array([[num1,2],[3,4]])
        self.mat2 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
        self.eigFunc = lambda num1: np.linalg.eig(self.mat2 + self.mat1(num1))
    def func1(self):
        eigval, eigvec = self.eigFunc(10)
        print(eigval)
c1().func1()
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will get the eigen values and eigen vectors for each of the matrices:

```
import numpy as np

class c1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mat1 = np.array([[11,21],[31,41]])
        self.mat2 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
        
        mat1_vals, mat2_vals = list(map(lambda mat: np.linalg.eig(mat), [self.mat1, self.mat2]))
        
        self.eigVal = [mat1_vals[0], mat2_vals[0]]
        self.eigVec = [mat1_vals[1], mat2_vals[1]]
        
        print('Eig Vals: ', self.eigVal)
        print('Eig Vecs:', self.eigVec)

if __name__=='__main__':
    c1()
```

**Output**

```
Eig Vals:  [array([-3.59729717, 55.59729717]), array([-0.37228132,  5.37228132])]
Eig Vecs: [array([[-0.82111408, -0.42601354],
       [ 0.57076411, -0.90471679]]), array([[-0.82456484, -0.41597356],
       [ 0.56576746, -0.90937671]])]
```

Thing to note is that you have to `map` the `lambda` function on some `iterable` object and then turn the `map` object into iterable to use it.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I can understand, there is not any simple way to recursively call eig function with lambda function. I mean, my essential code has NxN matrix.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope I helped, but I really don't understand what do you mean by `recursively` in this situation. What are your constraints in this case? I mean is it execution time or readability or memory resources? You should explain all this in the question, because it is not very clear.

Comment: In your answer, `self.mat1` is constant, but in my question I tried to put lambda in the `self.mat1`'s first element. What I want is writing a lambda function that depends on first value of `self.mat1` matrix and then I want to find eigenvalues of `self.mat` matrix. I said `recursively`, because I defined a lambda function for `self.mat1` and then I try to create a lambda function which is calling another lambda function. Isn't it recursively means?

Comment: `Recursive` means that you call a function `x` in side function `x` itself, in your case `self.mat1` is created in the first line of the `__init__`, then in line 3 you try to assign a newly created `lambda` again to two variables `self.eigVal` and  `self.eigVec`, which fails. Then the `c1::func1` method is called on integer `10`. I really dont see here a recursion, sorry. In addition, to use recursion, you have to define stopping condition, to prevent an infinite recursion, which is missing in your code also.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you again for your explanation.